# Duplicated Namespace is created on dll

Tags: vb.net, namespaces, visual-studio-2019, class-library

I'm creating a class library in VS2019 (VB.NET).

In the project properties, I used this root namespace: Customer.App.Classlibrary

When I'm compiling and using this library in another project, I need to import it as

```
Import Customer.App.Classlibrary.Customer.App.Classlibrary
```

The root namespace is duplicated....

Any suggestions???

Comment: Suggestion: show you code (enough to re-create the problem) *in the question*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike c#, in vb.net you don't need a namespace around your class, rather all vb.net code starts in the root namespace without specifying one. So when you have written your function to be used like this

```vb
Namespace Customer.App.Classlibrary

    Public Module MyStaticCLass
        Public Sub Foo()

        End Sub
    End Module

End Namespace
```

the namespace `Customer.App.Classlibrary` is added to the root namespace.

[image]

and your namespace becomes RootNamespace.ClassNamespace =  `Customer.App.Classlibrary.Customer.App.Classlibrary`

and you need to do

```vb
Imports Customer.App.Classlibrary.Customer.App.Classlibrary
```

**The fix:** just remove the namespace from your class definition

```vb
'Namespace Customer.App.Classlibrary

Public Module MyStaticCLass
    Public Sub Foo()

    End Sub
End Module

'End Namespace
```

and the imports will simply be

```vb
Imports Customer.App.Classlibrary
```

It might be a better idea to specify the root namespace to `Customer` and you can put your class in `Namespace App.Classlibrary` which will have a similar effect, with the added benefit of being able to separate classes in the same assembly into more granular namespaces. This depends on your desired design.

Comment: It worked as you said on normal classes. I just noticed, the issue is caused by a EDMX Model, that adds the extra name space.